# Python schema to match messages with optional arguments

Tags: python, json, jsonschema

I'm trying to use python's [schema](https://pypi.org/project/schema/) or [json schema](https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/) to validate a dictionary with nested dictionaries and lists:

```
message = 
    {"pagination":
    {"page":1,"perPage":25},
    "items":[{"id":1, "settings":[{"name":"name1","value":true}]},
             {"id":2 ,"settings":[{"name":"name2","value":true}}]}
    }
```

I need the following validations to occur:

1. "pagination" is in message
2. "items" is in message, and contains at least one member
3. Each item inside "items" contains an "id"
4. **We don't care about additional elements that an item might contain** (like "settings")

**How can I make the schema behave more like a regular expression?** (E.g: I don't know what additional elements on top of "id" the next message's items might contain, but as long as the first three conditions are met - I want it to be validated).

For example, the following message must be also recognized by the schema:

```
message = 
{"pagination":
{"page":1,"perPage":25},
"items":[{"id":1, "type": "A"},
         {"id":2 ,"type": "B"}]}
}
```

Comment: Welcome. What you want is possible with JSON Schema, however you need to show what you have done so far and explain it doesn't work, before asking for what you would like it to do.

Comment: However, it looks like the library you are using is NOT using JSON Schema. Sorry I won't be able to help.

Comment: I can switch to using this: https://pypi.org/project/jsonschema/.

Comment: It depends on what sort of validation you want to do. You will need to look at what each can do, and use the right tool for the job.

Comment: That's exactly what I'm trying to figure out - what tool and how should I be using to get a schema to act in a way similar to regular expression, so that a message which matches a certain pattern and might have variable amount of additional arguments which I don't care about, still will get validated.

Comment: You have validation requirements now, but you need to think about your future validation requirements. JSON Schema is limited in what it can validate, and I don't know what the other library can do. You need to think about what you will need to do, and read the library documentation for both to work out which library you want to use. This is not something someone else can answer for you, because only you know what you want.

Comment: You also MUST show what you have done so far, otherwise people here will be reluctant to help.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like a perfect use case for JSON Schema. JSON Schema validation is subtractive. All JSON documents are valid against the empty schema (`{}`). Each keyword in the schema then constrains that set of all JSON documents to something more useful. So, you can declare that an object must have an "id" property and not explicitly state that any other property is allowed because that's just the normal operating mode for JSON Schema.

I almost wrote this very simple schema for you as an example, but then decided it was better to just point you at "[Understanding JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/index.html)" so you can learn for yourself instead of me feeding you the solution. But, please do ask another (more specific) question if get stuck after reading that tutorial.